# Is it possible to get the RTT latency between two nodejs servers using only one request?

Tags: node.js, express, latency

I have a couple of nodejs/express servers which send http requests to each other. The initiator of the request uses the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library. I have noticed that by setting *time=true* on the options, you can get an estimation of the RTT on the initiator. However, I was wondering whether there is a way to get a similar estimation on the receiver of the request, without the need of a second request (on the opposite direction).

In other words, server A sends a request to server B as follows:

```
request.post({url:'B_url/ping', time:true, json: {x:y} }, 
    function (error, response, body)  {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
            console.log('timings: %j', response.timings) //i get what i need on server A here
        else 
            console.log(error)
    });
```

On server B, i got:

```
app.post('/ping', function (req, res) {
  //Is there any way to get the same (or similar) latency here???
  res.json({xx:yy}) 
})
```

Comment: Assuming your clocks are very well synchronized, you could include a timestamp in the request - and then the receiver could estimate RTT = 2 x RequestDelta, which is inaccurate if either clocks are not synchronized or the reply takes more or less time than the request itself.

Comment: I don't have the luxury to assume that :)

Comment: Absent synchronization or access to a common source of time, then there is no way, with 1 single message, of estimating how long the message took to arrive. And that is only half of the problem of estimating RTT.

Comment: My assumption was that there might be some way to access low-level information about the connection prior to the data being sent. For example, after the tcp handshake, theoretically both hosts can have an idea of the latency.